# How to setup the oracle database for localhost?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create database for localhost but couldnt able to get the **localhost credentials** for login. The connection get failed and showing " The network adapter could not establish the conenction ".

Comment: What database server are you using? Oracle is the name of a company, that produces many database products. Are you using Oracle XE?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Since it's tagged `oracle`, and that tag is specifically for the Oracle RDBMS, it's reasonable to assume we're talking about that.

Comment: I am using Oracle IDE 1.1.3.2769.

Comment: @Frank-schmitt agreed, but there is a big difference between [tag:oracle-xe], and [tag:oracle11g] in the context of this question.

Comment: @lakhan That's the IDE you are using. Do you have a database server installed on your local computer?

Comment: Yes. I have installed it. when i am trying for new connection it will ask for Conenction name and username , password. So i am not able to understand that from where actually i colud get that?

Comment: I have installed oracle 11g

Comment: You've only said you've installed a client, your IDE. That is really not the same as installing a server. You have to have the server software to create a database. Your IDE can only connect to an existing database.

Comment: Can you please share the link from where i should install it.

Comment: If you have a remote database, you can install only client, then add remote database to tnsnames.ora, if you don't have a remote database you have to to install Oracle Database Server. So tell us, if you have remote database or not.

Comment: @zarastutra i dont have remote database. I need to install it on my local machine only.

Comment: @zaratustra See i have this installed in my machine : 

Oracle - OraClient11g_home1: -Application developlment
-configuration and migration tool
-integrated management tool
-oracle installation products

Comment: Show us the file $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

Comment: @zaratustra There is no such folder oracle home, oracle installed in my machine contains only two folder Inventory and Bin..

Comment: you have to install oracle server here two files for [linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html) and for [windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html) download both files for your platform, extract into the same directory and run the file setup, it guides you through the installation process

Comment: remove the client, you don't need it

Comment: I found I couldn't install Oracle XE successfully on Windows for the same error. However running it via Docker worked great for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085168/1603489