# Local Database for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to be able to query a few small tables(which I have / can create) through Oracle SQL Developer.  For the love of all that's holy all I want is a way to host the tables or create a local database to aim Oracle SQL Developer to.

This topic is riddled with php, mysql, and wamp suggestions.  Once I began with each of them they seemed too far off the path.  I don't need features, bells and whistles. Just a simple place to drop a few tables and aim Oracle.

Please... please... I'm technically capable, just make this simple request possible for me and I'll bake you a pie.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Develop on local Oracle instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002/develop-on-local-oracle-instance)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question-- what problem are you having?  You can certainly download and install Oracle XE, install that locally, and point SQL Developer at that.  But I'm not sure how that relates to things like PHP or MySQL or wamp or anything else you're talking about...